# Override puppet variable in other class

Tags: overriding, puppet

I'm using the [postgresql puppetlabs](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/postgresql) module in my manifest. They have one parameter called `$service_manage` set to `true` by default in the `params.pp` file, so it looks like

```
class postgresql::params inherits postgresql::globals { 
   $service_manage = true 
   if $service_manage {
       # do something
   }
}
```

What exactly I want is that I want to set the variable `$service_manage`'s value as `false`, so that the `if` block doesn't apply to my manifest. I'm using it like this,

```
class mypostgres::config {
  class { 'postgresql::params' : service_manage => 'false' }
}
```

But it's failing with this error,

> SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Class[Postgresql::Params] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/modules/mypostgres/config.pp:4

I've also tried this

```
class postgresql::params { $service_manage = "false" }
```

but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to directly declare/include the class using the parameter, and not attempt to indirectly manipulate the `params` class. That class is being inherited in this module for defaults and logic. In fact, note: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/blob/master/manifests/params.pp#L1

The actual class inheriting that parameter is `postgresql::server`. Therefore, when you declare that class you want to override the parameter like this:

```
class { 'postgresql::server': service_manage => false }
```

and it will work correctly for you.

It is also worth noting that the `if` block of code inside `params.pp` for `$service_manage` does not actually exist, and should not exist if that design pattern is used by best practices.

Comment: exactly, that's what I was looking for. Thank you so much.